Controlled <select> component only, is being automatically reset in a form React 19
The controlled component also resets the "select" after the action is triggered.
but the "input" component does not.
"use client";
import { useActionState, useState } from "react";
function add() {
  return Date.now();
}
export default function Page() {
  const [state, formAction] = useActionState(add, 0);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("2");
  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <p>{state}</p>
      <p>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        <select
          name="gender"
          value={type}
          onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

see visual repro here
Repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-p3x321?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Your setup looks correct to me, but since this is an experimental feature maybe you can post it to React's github as a bug?
Anyways, this is how I would go around it using good ol' js/html:
// add onSubmit function
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form from resetting
    formAction();
  };
  
  return (
    // use onSubmit function instead of action since it seems to be buggy
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <p>{state}</p>
      // ...everything else same here
    </form>
  );
}

